# Foreign key to a not-yet-defined class in SQL Alchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, abstract-class, forward-declaration

We're trying to do something like this: Paradigm is an "abstract" (in Django terminology) base, that only contains common fields to all paradigms. It must have a foreign key (precisely, two of them) to Person, but Person is a Paradigm, declared later (in a separate file, even). Is this even possible using declarative API? I know how to construct a class having a foreign key to itself, but the problem is that this is dependent on a class: Person must have two foreign keys to *itself*, while another subclass of declarative_base(cls=Paradigm) must have two foreign keys not to itself, but Person.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Read the [`ForeignKey`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey.__init__) documentation:

> A single target column for the key relationship. A Column object or a column name as a **string**.

So you can refer to another table as:

```
user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

*There are many examples in the [Object Relational Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html) as well.*

Comment: Hm... of course, that was one of the first things I tried. But I get an error "sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Columns with foreign keys to other columns must be declared as declared attr callables on declarative mixin classes", which, to be honest, I don't really understand. I thought that means it couldn't be done, but now it seems like it meant something entirely different. :-/

Comment: A code example that produces your error would be helpful. Also take a look at [Mixing in Relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#mixing-in-relationships) documentation, which explains a cause for the error you are getting if you are mixing-in foreign-keys/relationships.

Comment: Yes, that would have helped if I knew that I was writing mixins. :-D What determines whether the base class is a mixin? Just its place in the bases tuple (first is real base, others are mixins)?